# Действия формы авторизации без сохранения данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Знатоки, может у Вас есть  идеи, как реализовать это?

Пользователь запускает программу, открывается окно авторизации. Если юзер ввел логин и пароль, а так же нажал "запомнить меня", то конфиг сохраняется с параметрами пользователя, но если другой пользователь захочет ввести свои данные и не станет нажимать "запомнить меня" - то программа все равно загрузит конфиг с сохраненными ранее данными, даже если пользователь вошел в систему под другим именем.

Мой вариант был такой: Допустим я запустила программу и увидела в окне авторизации сохраненные данные, вместо них я ввела свои и сняла галочку с "запомнить меня" - в этот момент программа должна создать копию файла конфигурации и сохранить меня туда, после чего работать с этим файлом, но там есть куча неудобств.

Есть ли какие нибудь варианты, как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Непонятно зачем сохранение какой-то конфига привязывать к кнопке "запомни миня", когда это можно делать совершенно ненавязчиво. Конфиг, даже персональный, обычно существует независимо от каких-то кнопок. А изначальный и единственно правильный смысл "запомнить миня" - чтобы при следующем запуске программа не спрашивала никакого логина и пароля, а сразу автоматически запускалась под тем пользователем, которого запомнила.

Comment: В десктопных приложениях это называют "запомнить пароль", "автологин". В браузерных веб-приложениях ни логин ни пароль не запоминается, но вместо этого выдаётся печенюшка, которую в следующий раз браузер предъявляет вместо логина. Технически  "запомнить пароль" это уже не назовёшь, вот и придумали "запомнить миня". А потом некоторые на этот термин "запомнить миня" начали придумывать совершенно бредовую функциональность вместо изначальной.

Comment: Если юзер нажал "запомнить" то его данные сохраняются в конфиг, но тут у меня баг - если я введу другие данные - они так же проверятся, программа впустит пользователя и загрузит тот конф, который уже был до этого от другого юзера.   При этом программа должна в любом случае загрузить конфиг, и он имеет статичное название..  Есть какой нибудь вариант исправить это?

Comment: Что Вам мешает сделать динамическое название конфига? String Konfig = "konfig_" + userId + ".konfig";

Comment: Понимаете, у меня в app.xaml.cs стоит условие - если конфига нет - создать его (с именем по дефолту), далее открывается логин окно и в нем снова проверка - если конфиг есть то загрузить с него логин и пароль в боксы логин окна. А если новый пользователь не сочтет нажать "сохранить учетку" а просто войдет - то что делать в этом случае? - создать новый конфиг с именем нового пользователя и его грузить? А что с ним делать по завершению программы? Нужно же от него избавиться, чтобы программа загрузила оригинальный конфиг, разве нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если речь идёт именно о функциональности «запомнить меня», имеет смысл делать так:

1. В [user-level settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759(v=vs.110).aspx) положите свойства, описывающие логин сохранённого пользователя и его пароль (или, возможно, хеш от пароля, это уж как ваша модель безопасности диктует). В начале они пустые. Отдельные конфигурационные файлы излишни.
2. При старте программы, если есть сохранённые логин и пароль, используйте их молча, не показывая диалоговое окно.
3. Если не сохранено ничего (или сохранён только логин), показывайте диалоговое окно ввода логина и пароля. Поле логина заполните заранее значением, если оно доступно.

   - Если диалог закрыт кнопкой OK, запомните в settings новый логин. Если юзер при этом поставил галку «запомнить меня», то запоминайте и пароль, в противном случае сбросьте его в null.
   - Если же диалог закрыт по-другому, просто ничего не меняйте, но не пускайте юзера дальше: он не авторизован. (Возможно, для этого случая нужен более разумный UI.)
4. В приложении сделайте кнопку logout, которая будет сбрасывать сохранённый пароль и открывать снова диалог login.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Елизавета: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что поможет!