# Cookie или их аналог C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cookie

Добрый день, делаю авторизацию на C#, проект WPF.
Появилась необходимость сделать кнопочку "Запомнить меня", пошарил в интернете, все варианты cookie связаны с asp.net, типовые или идентичны с этим:

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("MyName", "Alex", "/", "localhost");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
           "http://localhost:47747/CookieTest.aspx");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

    HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(
            responce.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
            txb_text.Text = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Как можно реализовать данную функцию без создания asp.net файлов?

Comment: Кажется, вам [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596335/10105).

Comment: Спасибо, именно так я уже и сделал, получилось вот так Settings.Default["login"] = login.Text;
Settings.Default["password"] = password.Password;
Settings.Default.Save(); Подскажите, если я в setting.settings в графе Scope указываю параметр User, то что я туда записываю будет доступно только на том компьютере на котором открыли программу?

Comment: Да, только на том компьютере.

Comment: Если сработало, закрою вопрос как дубликат.